# Create a variable with the name coming from a string variable

Tags: c++, variables, variable-names

I have a class say class A and a string variable `string name = "student"`. I want to create an instance of class A with the object name as student say `class A student;`
But i don't know the name of object prior; I have the object name present in the string variable.
Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: If it helps you, name them generically and save a name within the class.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? How would you use a variable whose name you don’t know?

Comment: @molbdnilo i back that observation^^ did not think about it, but you are very right.

Comment: We don't know what real problem you are trying to solve, but whatever it is you are probably looking for a `std::map`. That data structure lets you associate arbitrary data with a string.

Comment: It sounds like maybe [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) could be what you're looking for.

Comment: You might be confusing objects (which exist only when the program runs) with variables (which exist only in source code). If you want to name *objects*, you need to store the names somehow and associate them with the objects, for instance in a table.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: yes basically this is sub problem from the main problem i am trying to solve..Anyways I understood that we cant do that...

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't do that. There are no variable names once the code has been compiled.

Comment: yes, I understood the problem..